# How do I include c++ source code in an R package so a user can see it?

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I am writing an R package. Among many others is has a routine written in C++ called (say) myfoo. Now I would like a user of the package to be able to make changes to this routine, so they need to be able to see the source code.

I tried

```
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myfoo (double x)
```

and now there is a routine called myfoo in the package but it is only

```
myfoo
function (x) 
{
    .Call(`_packagename_myfoo`, x)
}
```

and not the source code.
So what is the appropriate way to make the source code available to a user?

Comment: a) The source code is always at the source repo so hyperlinks work, or b) you can always include example code in, say, `inst/examples` which becomes an installed directory `examples`.  This is once again a question that has nothing to do with Rcpp _per se_ but is about package.  Do you know about the excellent r-package-devel mailing list we added a few years ago to the set of R mailing list.  You could ask there.

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong keywords. I will check out the mailing list